# the impact of time step size on the results in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

Hello stack overflow community

am curious to know how the time step size value can impact the OpenModelica simulation results .

and how to optimize the sumilation periode so that we can accelerate the simulation to have results in a shorter time
and also what does impact the simulation time , like the computer performance  and the complexity of the code !!!

Comment: The last part of your question: what does impact a simulation runtime is though an interesting question but significantly different question. It goes too much beyond the choice of solvers communication step-size or tolerance. The question deserves another thread.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an explicit (fixed-step) solver such as Euler, the step size will have a major impact on the stability of the results.
If you use an implicit (usually multi-step) solver such as Dassl, the step size will not really impact any performance or results except the values printed to the result-file are interpolated to these points by the solver. If you want to make it run faster and be less accurate, you increase the tolerance of the solver.

https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/1.16/solving.html#integration-methods

Comment: i am using Dassl solver , that means that the step size will not impat the results but does it make the simulation run faster ?

Comment: The simulation speed itself should not impacted (only the part that is writing to result-file)

Comment: Note that a simulation will not always run faster with a larger tolerance. Sometimes it may counter-intuitively help to tighten the tolerance a bit - and sometimes the performance just seem random. (Note: for large tolerances; once the tolerance is below a certain threshold a smaller tolerance will require more time.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the nomenclatures. When you say in this post 'Step size' are you referring to the Interval parameter?

Moreover I've a couple of questions:

1. What's the scope of 'Initial time step' and 'Maximum time step'. How are they correlated with Interval and Tolerance?
2. What's the scope of 'Equidistant time grid' and 'Store variables at events' in the Output tab

Thanks